# Can i build both Native and Production?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, native, production

I'm tryng to build both native and production application, but when i reference *Ext.device* on my views, build the whole project using Sencha CMD and run on my local machine it's giving me this error:

> TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

I'm using:

- Sencha CMD 5.0.0
- Touch 2.3.2
- Phonegap
- Windows 7

I already *jshint* all files and they are correct. Had debug and discover that the Ext.device was making the run buggy...

The error was found on index.html in this piece of minified code (generated my CMD):

> function C(b) {   "undefined" != typeof console && (console.error ||
>   console.log).call(console, b) }

Any help will be appreciated,
Best Regards

Comment: You are gonna need to provide the relevant code, or there is not much anyone can do.

Comment: added the piece of code that give the error... Thanks, but my really question is if i can build on both native AND production...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment this line `build.optimize=${build.optimize.enable}` at `/.sencha/app/production.defaults.properties`

Clear all at Resources tab of your browser DevTool before run application